# How to rename images name using data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-learning, operating-system

I have a data frame that has `file_name`  and corresponding  `text`  and want to update the `file_name` and the image name in `imgs` folder by concatenating with some text or number the structure of `input_folder`  look like :

```
input_folder --|
               |--- imgs -- |-- 0.jpg
                            |-- 1.jpg
                            |-- 2.jpg
                            .........

               |--- train.jsonl
```

the `train.jsonl` file has :

```
{"file_name": "0.jpg", "text": "The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation"}
{"file_name": "1.jpg", "text": "of Atlanta's recent primary election produced \"no evidence\" that"}
```

```
path ="input_folder/train.jsonl"
df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf = input_file,   lines=True,)
print(df.head())

# rename file_name col
new_df['file_name'] = df['file_name '].apply(lambda x: 'A' + x)
# def rename(df['file_name'],new_df['file_name'])
```

What I am expecting is : updating the `file_name` column in resulting data frame with renaming the image name in `imgs` folder

```
out_folder --|
             |-- imgs -- |-- A_0.jpg
                         |-- A_1.jpg
                         |-- A_2.jpg
                           .........

             |---- train.jsonl
```

the `train.jsonl` file has :

```
{"file_name": "A_0.jpg", "text": "The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation"}
{"file_name": "A_1.jpg", "text": "of Atlanta's recent primary election produced \"no evidence\" that"}
```

After using the code snippet given by [@harriet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818186/how-to-rename-images-name-using-data-frame/75818522#75818522) I have the correct new images name and corresponding file_name in `train.jsonl` file: but I have a new issue which is a Unicode issue because the text is in the Hungarian language there is some special character not recognized will
example what I got in `train.jsonl` in output dir

```
{"file_name":"A_0.jpg","text":"El\u00e9gedetlenek az emberek a k\u00f6zoktat\u00e1ssal? Belf\u00f6ld - Magyarorsz\u00e1g h\u00edrei"}
```

But what I expect is :

`{"file_name": "A_0.jpg", "text": "Elégedetlenek az emberek a közoktatással? Belföld - Magyarország hírei"}`

Comment: I edited my original answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can import subprocess to execute a shell command to make your new directories and rename images accordingly:

```
import pandas as pd
from subprocess import call

path = "input_folder/train.jsonl"
df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf=path, lines=True,)

# make a duplicate dataframe
ndf = df.copy(deep=True)
filenames = list()
for i in range(len(ndf)):
    og_fn = ndf['file_name'][i]
    new_fn = 'A_{fn}'.format(fn=og_fn)
    filenames.append((og_fn, new_fn))
    ndf.loc[i, ['file_name']] = [new_fn]

# create output directory
call(['mkdir out_folder'], shell=True)

# copy original imgs folder into out_folder
dst = '/Users/username/.../out_folder'
src = '/Users/username/.../input_folder/imgs'
cmd = 'cp -a {s} {d}'.format(s=src, d=dst)
call([cmd, src, dst], shell=True)

# write the new dataframe to '/.../out_folder/train.jsonl'
with open(f'{dst}/train.jsonl', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(ndf.to_json(orient='records', lines=True, force_ascii=False))

for og, new in filenames:
    cmd = 'mv {og} {new}'.format(og=og, new=new)
    call([cmd], shell=True, cwd=dst + '/imgs')
```

this should give you an output_folder in the same directory as the `input_folder` with an updated train.jsonl and imgs directory (containing the images with updated names) inside -- let me know if this works for you. PS you must use deep copy because shallow copies will store references to the original dataframe's data.

EDIT.1 * you'll need open the new dataframe with the to encoding set to utf-8 before passing that file to the .to_json; and, pass the parameter force_ascii=False (force_ascii; bool, default True--Force encoded string to be ASCII.) *

EDIT.2 I think I understand what you're saying--it is because I did not rename the image names from the new jsonl itself (just the way you specified in the question)--you could save the filenames as tuples (original, new) in a list. Then, we can loop through those filename tuples and call 'mv {original} {new}' inside the imgs/ directory:

```
ndf = df.copy(deep=True)
filenames = list()
for i in range(len(ndf)):
    og_fn = ndf['file_name'][i]
    new_fn = 'A_{fn}'.format(fn=og_fn)
    filenames.append((og_fn, new_fn))
    ndf.loc[i, ['file_name']] = [new_fn]
    •
    •
    •
for og, new in filenames:
    cmd = 'mv {og} {new}'.format(og=og, new=new)
    call([cmd], shell=True, cwd=dst + '/imgs')
```

Comment: Sorry It is by mistike wanted to upvote 
now the encoding in `train.jsonl` is correct but caused another issue which is the name of the image is not the same as the name in the labels [issue](https://github.com/Mohammed20201991/DataSets/blob/main/repated%20char_A.JPG) the expected only `char A+numbers.ext`

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw, but I edited my answer again -- hope this helps!

Comment: I think the best way is to rename the resulting image with specific pattern [as mentioned her ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75840710/how-to-rename-images-with-specific-pattern)

Comment: The above issue could be solved by post-process after running the @harriet script, but I don't understand why it does not process all images. I have 500,000 images in `input_folder` results only 100,000 images in `output_folder`