# How to rename images with specific pattern?

Tags: python, regex, operating-system, glob

I have this image folder as shown below that has repated charchter name `A` I want only keep one letter `A` with rest of `numbers + ext`
the input :

```
input_folder --|
               |--- imgs -- |-- A_0.jpg
                            |-- A_A_A_1.jpg
                            |-- A_A_2.jpg
                            |-- A_A_A_A_3.jpg
                            |-- A_4.jpg
                            .........
```

I want to rename new image by keeping only Leter `A+numbers+.jpg`
for example if image name is `A_0.jpg` keep it if image name  `A_A_A_1.jpg` rename it to `A_1.jpg` and so on ..

I am trying to loop throght image folder and using `python` or `regular expression` with `py` following this articail [Rename with Regular Expression](https://medium.com/@nkrh/how-to-bulk-rename-with-regular-expression-and-python-2267580bb3a1)

the expacted output results in the same folder :

```
input_folder --|
               |--- imgs -- |-- A_0.jpg
                            |-- A_1.jpg
                            |-- A_2.jpg
                            |-- A_3.jpg
                            |-- A_4.jpg
                            .........
```

This issue caused by runing following script for `500 000 images` [rleated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818186/how-to-rename-images-name-using-data-frame)

Comment: So just `\w_\d+`?

Comment: Isn't this going to be problematic if you have, for example, these two files: A_1.jpg and A_A_1.jpg. Also, is it always repetition of 'A' and always the same extension?

Comment: @[DarkKnight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17580381/darkknight) yes, it is always repetition of 'A' and all images has same extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for the structure and file name pattern in the question. Other naming patterns may be problematic.

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import rename

PATH = Path('input_folder/imgs')
SEPARATOR = '_'
REPEAT = 'A'

for file in PATH.glob('*'):
    try:
        if len(t := file.stem.split(SEPARATOR)) > 1 and t[0] == REPEAT and t[-1].isdecimal():
            newfile = t[0] + SEPARATOR + t[-1] + file.suffix
            rename(file, PATH / newfile)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```